# When use Nethereum C# Library there are many CLOSE_WAITs in TCP Stack at node side

Tags: ether, myetherwallet, nethereum

When I use Nethereum methods (GetBlockWithTransactionsByNumber,GetBlockWithTransactionsByNumber and etc ) in loop, In TCP stack at node side accumulates a lots of CLOSE_WAIT. How can I fix this issue ? Please help this issue is very Significant for me

Here is example code:

```
Web3 etheriumService = new Web3(config.Address);
var lastBlockHashById = await EtheriumService.Eth.Blocks.GetBlockWithTransactionsByNumber.SendRequestAsync(new BlockParameter(ulong.Parse(savedBlockId)));
var dbBlock = await this.EtheriumService.Eth.Blocks.GetBlockWithTransactionsByNumber.SendRequestAsync(new BlockParameter(0));
//and etc
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GMiAG.jpg